# Sentiment analysis using images

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, sentiment-analysis

I am trying sentiment analysis of images.
I have 4 classes - Hilarious , funny very funny not funny.
I tried pre trained models like VGG16/19 densenet201 but my model is overfitting getting training accuracy more than 95% and testing around 30 
Can someone give suggestions what else I can try?
Training images - 6K

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to reduce overfitting:

- Implement **Early Stopping**: compute the validation loss at each epoch and a patience threshold for stopping
- Implement **Cross Validation**: refer to Section Cross-validation in
  https://cs231n.github.io/classification/#val
- Use **Batch Normalisation**: normalises the activations of layers to
  unit variance and zero mean, improves model generalisation
- Use **Dropout** (either or with batch norm): randomly zeros some activations to incentivise use of all neurons

Also, if your dataset isn't too challenging, make sure you don't use overly complex models and overkill the task.

Comment: I have tried the above things,I think the model is over complex I'll try to build a model from scratch